# Estimate the value of an inductor by its steady state response

Tags: inductor, steady-state

I have the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5Fvv1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The duty cycle of each sw is 50% and the frequency is 160kHz, at steady state I end with the following response:

[image]

Since I now the value of R I also know the current at R

[image]

Can I get from this data the value of L?

EDIT.

This will be the derivate:

[image]

Comment: if you can plot di/dt that would help

Comment: As the inductor is in series with the resistence it isn't the red graph di/dt?

Comment: red graph is I  di/dt would be the slope of that graph.

Comment: Is that a response you have measured? Because it doesn't look at all right. At steady state it would have an average DC bias of 8.5V, yet you for some reason have ~13.2V. Also that is very definitely not the gradient of the current waveform...

Comment: No, I just have the delta V at the resistance, I thought that will be enough to solve the equation, now I know I have to take the measurements again to get the actual dc bias.

Comment: @Tom But isn't 8.5V neither. At steady state the inductor current is always bigger than zero with that load at that frequency

Comment: The circuit is an L-R low pass filter which means that the steady state DC bias at the output will equal that at the input. If you are switching the input at 50% duty cycle between 0 and 17V, the input has an average voltage (DC bias) of (17+0)/2=8.5V, therefore the output must also. You cannot have a steady state DC bias of 13.25V unless there is something you are not telling us about the circuit or what your graphs are showing.

Comment: @Tom You're right, does that mean that the inductor with discharge completely at each cycle?

Comment: During the first half cycle it will charge. During the second half cycle it will discharge.

Comment: It reach zero current at the end of each cycle? I didn't measure that and then get confused with that and the continuous conduction mode of a converter.

Comment: Adding to what @TomCarpenter has already stated, or perhaps putting it in different words, for the circuit to have reached steady-state, it must swing symmetrically about the average value of the supply (bias) voltage.  It does not, according to your blue plot, so it either hasn't reached steady state yet, or something else is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotating your blue plot for greater detail yields the following, where V is the supply voltage, Vt is the voltage at which the waveform would begin to rise again, T2 is the time required for the waveform to fall to its lowest voltage, and T1 is the time when the waveform first starts to fall after building up from zero volts.

[image]

The time constant of an RL circuit is:

$$ t = k\ \frac {L}{R}\ , $$

and, in the circuit you've shown,

$$ t = T2 - T1 , $$

and

$$ k = ln \frac{V}{V-V_T} \ .  $$

Rearranging to solve for \$L\$, then, we have:

$$ L = \frac{R\ \ t}{k}  $$

For convenience, I've scaled the abscissa in units of seconds, and working out your problem with that in mind we can say:

$$ t = T2 - T1 \approx 3 \text { seconds ,}$$

$$ k = ln\ \frac{17V}{7.5V} \approx 0.82 ,$$

and, finally,

$$ L = \frac{R\ \ t}{k} = \frac{27\Omega \times 3s}{0.82} \approx 99 \text { henrys}  $$

Using your original microsecond time scale would yield \$\text {99 microhenrys, }\$ I believe.

However, something's wrong since the signal doesn't swing symmetrically about the supply's midpoint.

It should look something like this:

[image]

And here's the LTspice circuit list if you want to play with the circuit:

```
Version 4
SHEET 1 960 752
WIRE -16 128 -144 128
WIRE 256 128 64 128
WIRE 320 128 256 128
WIRE 448 128 400 128
WIRE 512 128 448 128
WIRE 256 176 256 128
WIRE 448 176 448 128
WIRE 208 192 160 192
WIRE -144 272 -144 128
WIRE 0 272 0 176
WIRE 160 272 160 192
WIRE -144 416 -144 352
WIRE 0 416 0 352
WIRE 0 416 -144 416
WIRE 48 416 48 176
WIRE 48 416 0 416
WIRE 160 416 160 352
WIRE 160 416 48 416
WIRE 208 416 208 240
WIRE 208 416 160 416
WIRE 256 416 256 256
WIRE 256 416 208 416
WIRE 448 416 448 256
WIRE 448 416 256 416
WIRE -144 496 -144 416
FLAG -144 496 0
FLAG 512 128 OUT
SYMBOL ind 416 144 M270
WINDOW 0 32 56 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 5 56 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName L1
SYMATTR Value 100µ
SYMBOL res 432 160 R0
SYMATTR InstName R1
SYMATTR Value 27
SYMBOL sw 256 272 M180
SYMATTR InstName S1
SYMBOL voltage 160 256 R0
WINDOW 3 24 96 Invisible 2
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 2
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMATTR Value PULSE(0 1 0 10n 10n 3u 6u)
SYMBOL sw 80 128 M270
SYMATTR InstName S2
SYMBOL voltage -144 256 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 2
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName V3
SYMATTR Value 17
SYMBOL voltage 0 256 R0
WINDOW 3 24 96 Invisible 2
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 2
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName V2
SYMATTR Value PULSE(1 0 0 10n 10n 3u 6u)
TEXT -136 440 Left 2 !.model SW SW(Ron=.01 Roff=1G Vt=0.5Vh=0)
TEXT -138 472 Left 2 !.tran 60u uic
```

Comment: thaks! What do you call k? it's an scaling factor? as far as I know the time constant is just L/R

Comment: When I Try to find L from the graph of the simulation you've made I got 146uH

Answer (score 1):

L is the reciprocal of the slope of current graph divided by the voltage across the inductor.